# [iOS]Can I trust iPhone's Settings>Battery Background Running Time?

Tags: ios, iphone

It says my app ran in the background for 30 minutes, but it actually ran for 6 hours.

I checked the log to see if the background was running.

Comment: Don't you have your answer already?? And in what way is this programming related?

Comment: Did it actually *execute* for 6 hours or did it execute for 30 minutes across a 6 hour period?  It would be very unlikely that your app actually actively executes for 100 % of the time when it isn't in the foreground

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.